# Use pandas to count value greater than previous value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the number of times a value is greater than the previous value by 2. 
I have tried

```
df['new'] = df.ms.gt(df.ms.shift())
```

and other similar lines but none give me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `diff`? Find the difference between consecutive values and check that their difference is greater than, or equal to 2, then count rows that are `True`:

```
(df.ms.diff() >= 2).sum()
```

If you need to check if the difference is exactly 2, then change `>=` to `==`:

```
(df.ms.diff() == 2).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

might be less than elegant but:

```
df['new_ms'] = df['ms'].shift(-1)

df['new'] = np.where((df['ms'] - df['new_ms']) >= 2, 1, 0)

df['new'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a specific difference, `gt` won't work. You could simply subtract and see if the difference is bigger than 2:

```
(df.ms - df.ms.shift() > 2).sum()
```

edit: changed to get you your answer instead of creating a new column. `sum` works here because it converts booleans to 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

your question was ambiguous but as you wanted to see a program where number of times a value is greater than the previous value by 2 in pandas.here it is :

```
import pandas as pd

lst2 = [11, 13, 15, 35, 55, 66, 68] #list of int



dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(lst2)) #converting into dataframe

count = 0 #we will count how many time n+1 is greater than n by 2
d = dataframe[0][0] #storing first index value to d

for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    #print(dataframe[0][i])
    d = d+2 #incrementing d by 2 to check if it is equal to the next index value
    if(d == dataframe[0][i]):
        count = count+1 #if n is less than n+1 by 2 then keep counting
    d = dataframe[0][i] #update index

print("total count ",count) #printing how many times n was less than n+1 by 2
```